# Webpack alias do not work completly in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webpack, import, intellisense

everything fine when [i import first component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqYLo.png), but i dont have intellisense when [trying to import any others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIQsm.png)

here is my current project tree

```
.
├── client
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── buttons
│   │   ├── form
│   │   └── index.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

inside folder components i have index.js file which export all components

here is my webpack alias
where clientPath is `path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');`

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        //...
        components: path.resolve(clientPath, 'components'),
    },
    symlinks: false,
}
```

and finally my jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "ES6",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "components": ["client/components/*"],
        }
    },
    "include": ["client"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

why does this happened and how to fix it ?